# Transiesta convergence issue

Tags: siesta, graphene

I have a graphene system (94 atoms - defective graphene) I was able to converge both right and left electrode runs in just 8 iterations. But the scattering run (transiesta) is not converging even after 10,000 iterations. Can anyone suggest what can be done....

Here are the parameters I use for my transiesta run:

## General variables

```
MeshCutoff    200.0 Ry
MaxSCFIterations     100000

DM.MixingWeight       0.05          # New DM amount for next SCF cycle
DM.Tolerance          1.0E-4         # Tolerance in maximum difference
DM.UseSaveDM          true          # to use continuation files
DM.NumberPulay         6

PAO.SplitNorm    0.150000
PAO.EnergyShift    0.005000  Ry
```

## MD variables

````
MD.MaxForceTol 0.01 eV/Ang
MD.TypeOfRun        CG
MD.VariableCell     false
MD.NumCGSteps        0
MD.InitialTimeStep      1
MD.FinalTimeStep        1
MD.LengthTimeStep       1 fs
ElectronicTemperature 300 K
MD.MaxCGDispl 0.05 Bohr
```
````

Comment: This might be related to https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/11297/transiesta-convergence?rq=1 and https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/12330/transiesta-scattering-calculation-not-converging